# Scale (vimeo)-video to 100% height of the parent container

Tags: html, css

I need to embed a vimeo-video into a container that has a width of 50% of the page and a responsive height. I don't care of the video being cropped on the right side but I need it to be scaled correctly and scale to the complete 100% height of the parent container.

My markup looks like that

```
<aside style="display:flex;">
<div class="theleftside" style="width:50%;">
<p>Text and other elements that will be changed frequently and 
I can't control their length but the height of that parents container 
basically shall set the height of the video of on the right side</p>
</div>
<div class="therightside" style="width:50%; overflow:hidden;">
  <iframe title="vimeo-player" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/783454352?autoplay=1&muted=1&h=a6fda96fc0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"    allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</aside>
```

How would I do that?